# How to make android use asp files for queries?

Tags: android, asp-classic, java-me

I was assigned a project which was made in J2ME (for blackberry devices), which uses original asp files in order to make a query to the client's database. The idea is to migrate this J2ME project to Android.

The problem is that I haven't found a way to use these asp files on my project (and I don't intend to change these files to another language, since they are a LOT of files), since they used J2ME classes for this, and I'm kind of remaking the project but with android; the asp files must be preserved as they are now.

I will leave some of the code in the original J2ME class, the asp name is registerUser.asp, if you need the asp code, I can post it later.
Thank you.

HTTPConnections.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpConnection;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class HTTPConnections {
private static String URL_SERVER        = "http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX";
private static String URL_BASE          = "BB";
private static String URL_DIR           = "BB"; 
private static String URL_REGISTER_USER = URL_SERVER+"/"+URL_BASE+"/"+URL_DIR+"/registerUser.asp";

public static boolean registerUser(String user, String password){
    StreamConnection s = null;
    PersistentStorage.database.setBD_AR__ID_TECNICO(0);
    RegisterUserParser handler=null;
    fin = getFinURL();
    try {

        s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(URL_REGISTER_USER+"?u="+user+"&p="+password+";deviceside=true"+fin);

        System.out.println(URL_REGISTER_USER+"?u="+user+"&p="+password+";deviceside=true"+";apn=web.iusacellgsm.mx");

        HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)s;

        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("El Status es: "+status);

        PersistentStorage.database.setLog(PersistentStorage.database.getLog()+URL_REGISTER_USER+"?u=-"+user+"- p=-"+password+"- Status= "+status+"\n");
        PersistentStorage.database.setLog(PersistentStorage.database.getLog()+"URL A LA BASE: "+URL_REGISTER_USER+"?u="+user+"&p="+password+"\n");

        PersistentStorage.database.setLog(PersistentStorage.database.getLog()+"STATUS: "+status+"\n");
        //Hector
        PersistentStorage.database.setLog(PersistentStorage.database.getLog()+"El final del URL es: "+fin+"\n");

        if (status == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            try {
                InputStream input = s.openInputStream();

                SAXParserImpl parser = new SAXParserImpl();
                handler = new RegisterUserParser();

                parser.parse(input, handler);
                input.close();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                //PersistentStorage.database.setLog(PersistentStorage.database.getLog()+"CATCH DEL SAX: "+e.getMessage()+"\n");
                System.out.println("Error: 1 "+e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException  e){
                System.out.println("Error: 500,000 "+e.getMessage());
                handler = null;
            }


            PersistentStorage.database.setBD_AR__ID_TECNICO(handler.getIdTecnico());

        }
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        PersistentStorage.database.setLog(PersistentStorage.database.getLog()+"CATCH 2: "+e.getMessage()+"\n");
        System.err.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println("Error: 2 "+e.getMessage());
    }
    if( handler!=null )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public static String getFinURL(){

    String finURL = "", user ="", pass="";
    String gSP = getServiceProvider();

    if(gSP.equalsIgnoreCase("IUSACELL") && red.equalsIgnoreCase("CDMA")){
        finURL = "";
    }
    else if(gSP.equalsIgnoreCase("IUSACELL") && !red.equalsIgnoreCase("CDMA")){
        finURL=";apn=web.iusacellgsm.mx";
    }
    else if(gSP.equalsIgnoreCase("TELCEL GSM") && red.equalsIgnoreCase("GPRS")){
        user=";TunnelAuthUsername=webgprs";
        pass=";TunnelAuthPassword=webgprs2002";
        finURL=";apn=internet.itelcel.com"+user+pass;
    }
    else if(gSP==null)
        finURL = "Dio null";
    else
        finURL = "";


    System.out.println("Mi URL es: "+finURL +" us: " + user+" pass: "+pass);

    return finURL;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Umh, the client J2ME code communicates with the backend ASP over HTTP, transferring payload, which is most likely XML, since it uses SAX parser to extract it to a strongly typed objects.

With this in mind, you don't have to change nothing in the backend code. You can take the existing client code, keep the part that establishes the connection, authenticates the user and so on, and replace the part that serializes the request payload or deserializes the response payload, using any of the Android-supported XML serialization mechanisms. I would recommend you use the [`SAXParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html) class, as this will minimize the changes you need to make.

As for the actual strongly-typed classes that need to be produced, you can defined them as POJ (plain old Java), and create constructors that take the data extracted from the XML and stuff it in them.

If you want to go fancy, and are not afraid of radical changes, I would recommend you get Jackson and use its [annotation-based databinding support](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/03/entry_467.html), as it's quite flexible and powerful.